# Hosting Apache2 log File

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, log, hosting

Currently I am trying to host my apache2 log file, with no luck. Here is the error i am getting

[tail error.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmuQF.png)

I am running the most up to date version of Apache. Here is my config.

[000-default-le-ssl.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3FFf.png)

I cannot seem to figure this out is this a permissions issue? Also I am running the most up to date v Ubuntu.

Finally here is the access for the log files:
[tail access.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnls3.png)

Comment: Do not show pictures of text include the test in the question. What version of Ubuntu both 20.04 and 20.10 could be considered most up to date.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache user, `www-data`, is not allowed to access the `/var/log/apache2` directory. It is forbidden for a lot of very good reasons. Openly hosting the `access.log` (or `error.log`) file can make your web server *much* easier for script kiddies and random bots to exploit. If you are trying to implement some barebones form of log-shipping, I would strongly advise you do all of the work over SSH connections. You can have a server in your house (or anywhere really) connect to the web server(s) at regular intervals with something like:

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@123.123.123.123:/home/user/apache_access_$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).gz /path/to/save/files
```

***Note:** This is just an example. If you *do* decide to do something like this, you'll need a scheduled job on your web server(s) that copies the current or previous Apache access log to a directory that your connecting account has access to.*

Do not make your servers an easy target.